# How can I filter elasticsearch responses from the request body, NOT the request url?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm searching an elasticsearch (v7.1) index using NEST and only need the ids of the returned documents. This can be accomplished with the following request URI in kibana:

## Request

```
GET exampleindex/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._id
```

## Response

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_id" : "123"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

## Question

How can I accomplish the same thing through the request body, without passing any query string parameters?

I'm hoping for something like this:

```
GET exampleindex/_search
{
  "filter_path": "hits.hits._id"
}
```

But that does not work:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [filter_path].",
        "line": 2,
        "col": 18
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [filter_path].",
    "line": 2,
    "col": 18
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've added answer for you, was it helpful i.e is that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html):

```
GET /_search
{
    "_source": false
}
```

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, but it still has `took`, `index`, etc;. I want the output to _only_ include `hits.hits._id`

Answer (score 0):

Actually a **filter_path** parameter can be used to reduce the response returned by Elasticsearch. So it work with

```
GET exampleindex/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._id
```

but **not on request body** because it doesn't support it that's why you're getting error.

If you use `source: false` like below still you get the meta data `_index`, `_type`, `_id`, `_score` which will must be returned by elasticsearch.

N.B: **Currently there is no way to remove those meta data from response**

```
GET exampleindex/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "_source": false
}
```

So. If you use any server side language e.g python/php or anything else you can filter out the id only to a array/list. For an example:

```
import elasticsearch
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()

res = es.search(
    index=your_index, 
    body={"query": {"match_all": {}}, "size": 10, "fields": ["_id"]})

ids = [d['_id'] for d in res['hits']['hits']]
print(ids) # it will contain only the ids
```